# What is wrong with this code-(I have to find the no. of letters in longest word)

Tags: java

I print out st and it gives the last word.But on printing int lon,which is to count the highest no. of letters in a particular word,it returns 0....

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Scn
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        int i,a;
        int len=0;int lon =0;
        String st="";
        char b;
        a = s.length();
        for(i =0;i<a;i++)
        {
            b = s.charAt(i);
            if(b ==' ')
            {
                if(len>lon)
                    len=lon;
                st="";/makes st empty
            }
            else 
            {
                st=st+b;
                len=st.length();/Count no. of letters
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: First problem with your code: [it's not formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Really sorry. This is my first time on this website. I wanted to edit it,just cant do it that quickly. I pressed ctrl+k but i did it twice...

Comment: you never assign a value to `lon`, you just initialize it with `0`

Comment: Right.  I suggest you go back to my [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845) for homework help and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Then it gives the error that lon isnt initialized

Comment: @JoeC "_A FAQ should generally have a single canonical answer, unless it's essential to break it into sections for better organization. Please consider merging this with the existing answer, fitting in those parts that are unique to homework questions and are not otherwise addressed, then deleting this._"

Comment: It was my error and i've got it. I feel asking i have a problem with the code doesnt violate a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Change `len = lon;` to `lon = len;`

That should do the trick.